# is there any jquery plugin to stretch any div to take the full screen

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a solution where any image element can be stretched to fit the screen size (scale it) and used as a background for that page.
Please note I am not looking for a one page background image solution what backstretch or vegas jquery plugin does !

```js
    <body>
                <div class="somecss">
                        <img src="images/bg1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="somecss">
            <img src="images/bg2.jpg">
                </div>
    <div class="somecss">
      <img src="images/bg3.jpg">
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: "Please note I am not looking for a one pages background image solution what backstretch or vegas plugin does !" I have no idea what you mean by this. Please clarify.

Comment: vegas and backstretch are two jquery plugins which makes an image to fit the screen as a background image. but they make the page single page. My requirement is if lets say there are 3 divs each one should take full device screen size. whether there has content or not.

Answer (score 1):

CSS `background-size: cover` might be what you need. It will fill the image to the size of the container. No JavaScript required.

> `cover` tells the browser to make sure the image always covers the
>   entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little
>   bit off one of the edges.

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: checked neither it does. if the image is bigger than the screen height it doesn't fix it.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Maybe you are doing something wrong? It doesn't matter if the image is bigger than the screen or not. You just need a fixed size container.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from the phrasing of your question, but I think that what you want is to stretch and fix an image to the background of a page. This can (and should) be achieved solely through CSS, with no need for jQuery.

```
body {
  background-image: url(http://example.com/your/image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: none;
}
```

But for completeness' sake:

```
$.fn.setBackgroundImage = function(url) {
  return this.css({
    backgroundImage: url,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'none'
  });
};

$.setBackgroundImage = function(url) {
  $(document.body).setBackgroundImage(url);
};
```

Comment: I dont want to make the body background full screen. I want each div to take full screen and make the image as their background.

Answer (score 0):

If its specifically an image element rather than a background-image property you want to be resized, you need to determine the proportions then assign the relative class to fit the screen

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.container').find('img').each(function() {
    var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
    $(this).addClass(imgClass);
  })
})
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/vhotnp1x/

Comment: checked it doesn't work ! it doesnt make the image fit the screen. it does so in one direction.